# Output String NOT Boolean Using Comparison OR || Operator

Tags: php

In JavaScript, I use the comparison "or" operator, || to check if a result is present. If not, print something else, e.g.:

```js
console.log( '' || 'Yes' ); // Yes
```

In the above code snippet, "Yes" is printed.

However, in PHP, the behavior is different, e.g.:

```
<?php

echo '' || 'Yes'; // 1

?>
```

Instead of printing "Yes," PHP parses the boolean statement and it evaluates it as 1 (true).

In PHP, how can I achieve the same behavior as in JavaScript without using the ternary operator.

Comment: `echo '' | 'Yes';`

Comment: @AbraCadaver - Although that works for the specific example, it doesn't in [the general case](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php): *"If both operands for the &, | and ^ operators are strings, then the operation will be performed on the ASCII values of the characters that make up the strings and the result will be a string. In all other cases, both operands will be converted to integers and the result will be an integer."*

Comment: Are you looking for `echo '' ?: 'Yes';`? Not posting an answer as I'm actually confused/surprised no one suggested that yet; I might be missing something obvious (also there's probably a good duplicate anyway).

Comment: Hi Jeto, thanks for the suggestion but I'm looking for a way to do without using the ternary operator. I updated my question stating so. AbraCadaver's suggestion is the closest one .

Comment: @GTSJoe You mean replacing `||` with `?:` is not good enough, but replacing `||` with `|` is fine? ... really? :)

Comment: @Jeto - I'd post the `?:` as an answer, [the description](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) sounds exactly right: *"Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise."* [Example](https://ideone.com/7B4jdq). That's **exactly** what `||` does in JavaScript. GTS Joe - E.g.: `echo '' ?: 'Yes';`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sure, I'll go ahead and do this then. I'm guessing GTSJoe didn't notice I used the shorthand version in the above comment.

Comment: When would you use this?  Any more examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the [shorthand version of the ternary operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) (even though that makes it no longer a ternary operator :)).

It will evaluate to its first operand if the condition is *truthy*, and fall back to the right operand if it's not:

```
echo '' ?: 'Yes';  // Yes
```

**Demo (with a few examples): https://3v4l.org/ZXRE5**

See [this page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) in the manual for details as to what kind of values are considered *falsy* (everything else being therefore *truthy*).

Comment: I just have to laugh at people calling this the shorthand version of the ternary operator (and PHP's documentation calling the long version "the" ternary operator), since of course, the above isn't a ternary operator, it's a binary operator (an operator accepting two operands) variant of a ternary operator (an operator accepting three operands). :-) (Yes, my wife **did** buy me a "pedant" pin for Christmas, what's your point?)

Comment: BTW, I later learned this technique is called "short-circuit evaluation," and it's used in various different languages.